# Push file at the end of questionnaire (json) - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json that contains questions and answers, which are displayed individually in divs. The user can click on an answer and I have a function onClick that goes to the next question

```
() => setQuestionIndex(() => questionIndex + 1
```

I would like that when the json "questions" is finished, a new json "solutions" is pushed:

```
onAnswer={() => {
        if (questionIndex === question.length) {
          () => history.push('/forms/solutions')
        } else {
          () => setQuestionIndex(() => questionIndex + 1)
        }
      }}
```

When I only use `() => setQuestionIndex(() => questionIndex + 1` it skips to the next questions perfectly, but the conditional statement doesn't work, any guesses?

Full code:

```
const Form = enhance(({
  styles, scenario, questionIndex, setQuestionIndex
  }) => {
const { questions } = scenarios[scenario];
const questionTabs = questions.map((q, i) => {
if (i === questionIndex) {
  return <Tab key={i} {...css(styles.tabActive)}> {i} </Tab>
}
return <Tab key={i} {...css(styles.tab)}> {i} </Tab>
})

const questionPanels = questions.map((question, i, history) => {
return (
  <TabPanel key={i}>
    <Question
      question={question.question}
      answers={question.answers}
      visualAnalogScale={question.VAS}
      //onAnswer={() => setQuestionIndex(() => questionIndex + 1)}
      onAnswer={() => {
        if (questionIndex === question.length) {
          () => history.push('/forms/solutions')
        } else {
          () => setQuestionIndex(() => questionIndex + 1)
        }
      }}
    />
  </TabPanel>
 );
});
```

Comment: Why your statement is wrapped by `{...}`?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What is the expected behaviour? Where is `setQuestionIndex()` function code? Does it use the `history` object to "skip to the next questions"?

Comment: The conditional statement should say that if the question index is equal to the number of questions (the end of the json file), then push push the solutions json file, otherwise go to the next question. I've updated with the full code

Comment: With the conditional statement when I click on an answer it doesn't skip to the next question. But if I only use this line `onAnswer={() => setQuestionIndex(() => questionIndex + 1)}` it works. But I don't get the solutions json at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an off by one error? If so, this line

```
if (questionIndex === question.length) {
```

Should be:

```
if (questionIndex === question.length - 1) {
```

Also why is everything a function?